# Undefined Control Sequence \institute

Tags: errors, sv-classes

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm using a template provided by Springer. I'm running their default template known as `author.tex` and I'm provided an error message that says `\institute` is an undefined control sequence. I've never used Latex before and I'm required to follow this template. I have attached the relevant code below.

```
\begin{document}
\title*{Contribution Title}
% Use \titlerunning{Short Title} for an abbreviated version of
% your contribution title if the original one is too long
\author{Name of First Author and Name of Second Author}
% Use \authorrunning{Short Title} for an abbreviated version of
% your contribution title if the original one is too long
\institute{Name of First Author \at Name, Address of Institute, \email{name@email.address}
\and Name of Second Author \at Name, Address of Institute \email{name@email.address}}
%
% Use the package "url.sty" to avoid
% problems with special characters
% used in your e-mail or web address
%
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

All the required packages have been included in the default implementation of the template. I have not changed anything in the source code and yet it fails to compile with the error as described above. It'd be great if anyone with relevant experience on this could help me debug the problem.

Edit: The link to the complete template is below.

https://www.springer.com/de/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/manuscript-preparation/5636

In this link, please click on Latex Template -> Contributed Books. Inside the folder that's downloaded, please click on author.tex

Comment: Please share a link to the template.

Comment: Could you provide a complete minimum example that starts with `\documentclass{...}`

Comment: I have edited the question to provide the link to the template. The complete example is rather large to put inside the question, but I hope the link should be okay.

Comment: @sosale151: If I use the `svmult.cls` which can be found from your `contributed book` link in your post, your example runs without problems

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I do not believe that creating a minimal document has to be large, if you **only need to show a code that produces the error you mention**. More info can be found in: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: I did the following: (1) download zip, run through virus check; (2) create a new directory, move zip into that directory, unzip the archive; (3) change into the templates directory with `cd templates`; (4) create a symbolic link to the relevant class with `ln -s ../styles/svmult.cls ./`; (5) execute `pdflatex author.tex`; (6) open `author.pdf` in PDF viewer. As with @ChristianHupfer, I don't get any errors. If you are on Linux or OS X, try following exactly those steps. If you are Windows, at step (4) copy the class file into the working directory instead and adapt the commands appropriately.